# Python: data import from MSSQL 'Incorrect syntax' at WHERE statement

Tags: python, sql-server, export-to-csv

With Python I want to create multiple csv files with data from MS SQL. In MS SQL I have a table with article names and some article information. Article names show up multiple times in the table with varying article information. The script should create one csv file per article name. I did the same script for article numbers (integer) and it worked fine. But with article names (varchar:letters, numbers) I get this error message:

ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'SomeArticleName'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
--> I guess the WHERE statement is the problem

```
import pyodbc
import csv

conn= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                     r'servername'
                     r'DATABASE = mydatabase;'
                     r'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT [ArticleName] from [mydatabase].[dbo].
[mytable]")
allarticles = cursor.fetchall()
for article in allarticles:
    anr = article[0]
    cursor.execute("SELECT *  from [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable] WHERE 
[ArticleName] = " + str(artikel[0]))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    myfile = 'mypath'+anr+'.csv'
    with open(myfile, 'w') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator = '\n')
        for row in rows:
            a.writerow(row)

conn.close()`
```

I printed the article names from 'allarticles' and they show up.

Comment: Look at the contents of `artikel[0]` and how the full concatenated query string would look. It seems it creates an invalid query. Also, be sure to use parametrized queries if the condition contains any variable value.

Comment: Doesn't look like your string `str(artikel[0])` has any delimiters. You need to add an apostrophe on each side of that value. When you debug the value should look like `'article name'`. But I would highly suggest using a parameterized query here for security reasons and also to defeat this issue.

Comment: `article[0]` <> `artikel[0]`

Comment: article[0] <> artikel[0] was just a typo when editing the code to publish it here.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with a parameterized query.